# Contribution Confirmation page back button redirects forward instead

Tags: civievent, civicontribute

On all our event registration forms, on the Confirmation page, there is the option of Go Back or Continue.

1) If I click Go Back when Paying offline, the form goes back to the previous page so I can make edits.

2) But if I opt to pay via PayPal Pro, the Back button instead moves me forward and I end up with a successful PayPal transaction -- obviously not what I wanted when I clicked back!

Any one else experience this or know what might cause it?

Comment: What version of civicrm are you using?

Comment: I'm using Joomla 3.9.1 and civiCRM  5.8.0